# Java' SimpleDateFormat parsing dates incorrectly

Tags: java, simpledateformat, date-format, date

I am trying to parse timestamps using the format "yyyymmddHHssmm".
I have two such time stamps:

```
String timeStamp1 = "20190612221303"//this means 12June2019 10:13:03pm
String timeStamp2 = "20190512222303"//this means 12May2019 10:23:03pm
```

So I am trying to convert these timestamp string to java date using the following :

```
Date date1= new SimpleDateFormat("yyyymmddHHssmm").parse(timeStamp1);
Date date2 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyymmddHHssmm").parse(timeStamp2);
```

So obviously when I do a

```
System.out.println(date1.getTime() > date2.getTime());
```

I would expect the above statement to print true.
But alas it prints false.

Inface the .getTime() of Date prints 1547310793000 for date1 and 1547310803000 for date2, which is obviously incorrect.
Could someone point out what is going on here.

Comment: Note also `HHssmm` should be `HHmmss`.

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `LocalDateTime` and `DateTimeFormatter`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The format that you have used:yyyymmddHHssmm is ambiguous.

I believe the 5th and 6th characters are used to define months.
Use MM in caps for that.

You have used small mm, which means minutes

Answer (score 2):

In the format string, you have `mm` twice: `yyyymmddHHssmm`. The first occurrence should be [`MM`, for month of year.](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Answer (score 2):

What is happening is that you are using

```
m   Minute in hour
```

And your TimeStamp it is parsing with date

```
Sat Jan 12 22:03:13 Date1
Sat Jan 12 22:03:23 Date2
```

You need to use

```
M   Month in year
```

Check more in the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Answer (score 1):

Your String passed to SimpleDateFormat should be `yyyyMMddHHmmss` . Take look here which letter stands for which thing in that formatter. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html